# Main loop for a text-based Blackjack game

Tags: python, beginner, playing-cards

Is there any way to reduce this code? It repeats itself, but I cannot find any way to reduce it because it is only repeating inside one elif. Sorry I'm a beginner my code is quite bad
It repeats here:

```
           onze(joueurs)
           print("joueur", a + 1, "a", joueurs[a])
           time.sleep(1)
           while sum(joueurs[a]) < 21 or 11 in joueurs[a]:
```

The code :

```
while t:
    input("Appuyez sur entrer pour continuer...")
    for a in range(nb):
        while sum(joueurs[a]) < 21 or 11 in joueurs[a]:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("main du joueur", a + 1, ":", joueurs[a], "Total :", sum(joueurs[a]))
            if sum(joueurs[a]) > 21 and 11 in joueurs[a]:
                onze(joueurs)
                print("joueur", a + 1, "a", joueurs[a])
            ask = input("Joueur {} voulez vous une carte ?(oui/non)".format(a + 1))
            if ask == "oui":
                askoui(joueurs)
            else:
                asknon()
                t = False
                break
        if sum(joueurs[a]) == 21:
            print("joueur", a + 1, "a BLACKJACK")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif sum(joueurs[a]) > 21 and 11 in joueurs[a]:
            onze(joueurs)
            print("joueur", a + 1, "a", joueurs[a])
            time.sleep(1)
            while sum(joueurs[a]) < 21 or 11 in joueurs[a]: 
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print("main du joueur", a + 1, ":", joueurs[a], "Total :", sum(joueurs[a]))
                if sum(joueurs[a]) > 21 and 11 in joueurs[a]:
                    onze(joueurs)
                    print("joueur", a + 1, "a", joueurs[a])
                ask = input("Joueur {} voulez vous une carte ?(oui/non)".format(a + 1))
                if ask == "oui":
                    askoui(joueurs)
                else:
                    asknon()
                    t = False
                    break
            elif sum(joueurs[a]) > 21:
                perdu(joueurs)
                t = False
        elif sum(joueurs[a]) > 21:
            perdu(joueurs)
            t = False
```

Comment: you can always put code in function and use this function. But for two lines it can be better to keep current version.

Comment: Could you share your whole code? That would make it easier to give advice.

Answer (score 1):

It's "Pythonic" to iterate through items, so assuming that `len(joueurs) == nb`, your main `for` loop can be:

```py
    for a, joueur in enumerate(joueurs):
```

which means all your `joueurs[a]` become `joueur`. I'm quite surprised that `onze`, `askoui` and `perdu` functions take the whole `joueurs` list, not just the current player. How does that work?

I'd guess that the check for possible `onze` action, which I take it is converting an ace down from 11 points to 1, could more comfortably fit within the `askoui` function when our current player gets another card, non? Then this main routine could just check against 21, or perhaps even better the `askoui` function could return a status value.

Difficult to be more specific without getting into some of these auxiliary functions. Here's my best guess at a reduced code that I think should do the same  as you presently have, plus some outstanding issues:

```py
while t:
    input("Appuyez sur entrer pour continuer...")
    for ix, jr in enumerate(joueurs):
        jID = ix+1
        while sum(jr) < 21:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("main du joueur", jID, ":", jr, "Total :", sum(jr))
            ask = input("Joueur {} voulez vous une carte ?(oui/non)".format(jID))
            if ask == "oui":
                askoui(joueurs) # why all joueurs?
                if sum(jr) > 21 and 11 in jr:
                    onze(joueurs) # why all joueurs?
            else:
                asknon()
                t = False # immediate halt to play for all players?
                break
        if sum(jr) == 21:
            print("joueur", jID, "a BLACKJACK")
            time.sleep(1) # then play continues
        elif sum(jr) > 21:
            perdu(joueurs) # why all joueurs?
            t = False
        # play continues without message if sum(jr)<21 ?
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I couldn't post all my code because Stackexchange lock the amount of code that can be posted. I understood your idea and I think I could make that work. I'll get back to you as soon as I try ! thanks for your answer